# Javascript - Can't access items of HTMLCollection?

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make an element clickable on my site. I am retrieving the 3 items to be clickable with GetElementsByClassName() and attempting to manipulate the object using the .item() syntax. When assigning the item to a variable, it has a value of NULL even though the item can be seen in the console. The collection shows in the console but I am unable to access its items. Code included below. The page can be viewed at https://clearrock959.com . How can I access the items?

```js
function replace() {
  let list = document.getElementsByClassName('cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption shortcode_animated');
  var x = list.item(1);
  console.log(list);
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Not sure where you learned about `item` with an HTML Collection, just use bracket syntax

Comment: @epascarello — Somewhere very out of date and Internet Explorer-centric :(

Comment: It still works though `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption shortcode_animated").item(0))` to show the first. item(1) might not exist if there is only one of them

Comment: How many items are in your collection called list? If it contains only 1 item it should be accessible by list.items(0).

Comment: The list has a length of 3.

Comment: I have used bracket syntax earlier in trying to solve the problem. This is the point I am at in the rabbit hole. Both brackets and () have been used.

Comment: @CharlesJ.Barnett, To keep it simple,  Your ```list``` is an array of HTML collection so you need to use for loop to get each individual item..

Comment: Please do what has already been requested in the first comment: add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem.

Comment: documentation says when item returns null, the index is out of the range. So sounds like it is not finding the elements. The query is LIVE so if the elements are added after, than it will appear on the list.

Comment: @Charles J. Barnett: Your code works fine using any classname of this stack site. So the issue has to be somewhere else.

Comment: Your current code `let list = document.getElementsByClassName('cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption shortcode_animated')[0];` should be `let list = document.getElementsByClassName('cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption shortcode_animated');` then you can do `var x = list[1];
                             console.log(list);
                             console.log(x);`

Comment: Of course, wrote an answer explaining what the issue is the OP is seeing and bam... closed. :)

Comment: @mplungjan I have changed the code to that as it was what I had earlier. Check it on the site now. X is returning undefined. This is the code that I had in an earlier attempt.

Comment: Live HTML Collection and lazy loading of console..... probably bites ya

Comment: @CharlesJ.Barnett see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LIs do not have  shortcode_animated class to begin with so unless you add them later you need

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption")[0])
```

```html
<ul class="cmsmasters_gallery cmsmasters_3 cmsmasters_more_items_loader">
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>EQUIPMENT</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>SERVICE</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>PREVENTATIVE MAINTENANCE</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or safer

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".cmsmasters_gallery_item.cmsmasters_caption")[0])
```

```html
<ul class="cmsmasters_gallery cmsmasters_3 cmsmasters_more_items_loader">
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-Service-1-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>EQUIPMENT</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-preventative-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>SERVICE</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li class="cmsmasters_gallery_item cmsmasters_caption">
    <figure><img width="600" height="446" src="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1.jpg" class="attachment-full size-full" alt="" srcset="https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1.jpg 600w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1-300x223.jpg 300w, https://clearrock959.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/AppleFitness_Hotlinks-equipment-1-580x431.jpg 580w"
        sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, 600px" />
      <figcaption>PREVENTATIVE MAINTENANCE</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```